# how to appear multiple line in r(package plot3d)?

Tags: r, spline, rgl

How can I draw multiple lines(splines) in `plot3d`??

I have a  3-dim coordinate. I tried one 3d line graph so far.
Here is my sample data.

```
x <- c(2,3,4,6,2,4)
y <- c(2,4,5,3,3.43,5.2)
z <- c(5.2,4,8.1,2.8,5.5,5.5)

x1 <- c(2,5,2,5,6)
y1 <- c(2.5,5,4,5)
z1 <- c(3,4.2,8.1,3,4)
```

Comment: I formatted the data part and revised the question by adding/deleting some words.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lines3d(x,y,z, col = "red")
lines3d(x1,y1,z1, col = "green")
```